# comparing float inequality (in python)

Tags: python, floating-point

```
assert tlf.z >= tlb.z, (tlf.z,trf.z)
AssertionError: (0.5, 0.5)
```

As can be seen, I'm suffering from precision problems.  How can I rephrase the assert so it does pass for close enough values (how big should the fudge-factor be?) and then fix the rhs should it actually be smaller than the lhs so that it becomes strictly equal?

Comment: How big should the tolerance be? As big as it needs to be, and no bigger.

Comment: ho ho and this can be determined how?  I was going to get at 0.000001 for 32-bit

Comment: Well, only you can answer this. Only you know where the imprecision comes from. So, just as big as you need, and no bigger.

Comment: For what it's worth, for such tests, I try to make my tolerances proportional to the magnitude of the values being compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
EPSILON = 10 ** -12
assert tlf.z >= tlb.z - EPSILON, (tlf.z,trf.z)
tlf.z = max(tlf.z,tlb.z)
```

Essentially, you have to define the tolerance you're willing to have for "greater than or equal", and account for it.

What value to pick for EPSILON is a difficult question.  It depends on the source of your error, and the number of calculations between that source and the comparison.  If there are few calculations, a smaller value for EPSILON is a good bet.  I would try the example, and adjust if you still find problems.

Comment: I think that should be `assert tlf.z >= tlb.z - EPSILON`. Suppose the two values really *are* equal; the "+ EPSILON" will make the assertion fail.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the answer given by willm1 is correct.
Let me explain.

The following expression:
    `tlf.z >= tlb.z - EPSILON`
is equivalent to:
    `(tlf.z > tlb.z - EPSILON) or (tlf.z == tlb.z - EPSILON)`

If `tlf.z > tlb.z` is true, even by a difference smaller than EPSILON, then `tlf.z > tlb.z - EPSILON` will also be true. No matter what the value of EPSILON. Instead, the correct form is:
    `tlf.z > tlb.z + EPSILON`
As for the second expression, `tlf.z == tlb.z - EPSILON`, it will only be evaluated as true if `tlf.z` and `tlb.z` differ exactly by `EPSILON`, which is not what we want. Instead, we want the difference between them to be less than `EPSILON`:
    `abs(tlf.z - tlb.z) <= EPSILON`

Concluding, `tlf.z >= tlb.z - EPSILON` should be written as:
    `(tlf.z > tlb.z + EPSILON) || (abs(tlf.z - tlb.z) <= EPSILON)`

**Update**:
I was looking at some code, and all of a sudden I noticed that `(tlf.z > tlb.z + EPSILON) || (abs(tlf.z - tlb.z) <= EPSILON)` is actually equivalent to `tlf.z >= tlb.z - EPSILON`.
When we're looking for the similarity, `abs(tlf.z - tlb.z) <= EPSILON`, we want `tlb.z` to be in the following gray area:
[image]
When we're looking for `tlf.z > tlb.z + EPSILON`:
[image]
Hence, we're really looking for:
[image]
Which is the same as `tlf.z + EPSILON >= tlb.z` (equivalent to `tlf.z >= tlb.z - EPSILON`).
In that case, willm1 was actually right. Sorry :)

Comment: nicely answered.

In my own code I ended up doing `math.fabs(tlf.z-tlb.z) < 0.000001`

Comment: Thank you. In that case you're checking for similarity only.

Comment: quite right, I wrote that forgetting the original question; for `>=` I'd just subtract *half* the fudge factor from the rhs

Comment: Was looking at the code that I have and I found out that the conditions I wrote are actually equivalent to the one from willm1.